# Necessary repair of termite damage to floor joists in crawl space?

Tags: joists, crawlspace, termite

I have what appears to be some minimal termite damage to a few floor joists near my front and back porches. No floor sag or leveling issues that I am aware of. There is not a current infestation. I have a current termite bond and the house was treated and has been inspected yearly. The damage is several years old now.
I am looking for some guidance on the best way to remediate the damage. Should I sister the joists? Is there a better way to repair? I am trying to figure out if this is a DIY job or if I need to have a contractor do this work.
I am not the most handy, but my research on this site and others indicates this may not be a big job and could be completed in a half day or so. Pictures included but can take more as necessary.

[image]   [image]

[image]   [image]

Comment: Take a nail/screwdriver/something and push into the damage sections.  From the pictures that is probably all you need to do, the damage does not look bad enough to fix.  If the nail goes all the way though, you might want to nail/screw some wood up against it to add extra support for the floor.  Hard flooring like tiles do not like any movement.

Comment: I appreciate that. A screwdriver will not go all the way through. Would you add wood filler or anything? Or just leave it completely?

Comment: Wood filler is used to smooth wood gouges before painting.  It won't help but can't hurt either.  I would clean all the non wood stuff(grey) off and keep an eye on it(once every two months), to catch any re infestation.

Comment: @ crip659,  combine your 2 comments into an answer, as this is THE answer for the question.

Comment: Agree that it looks minimal from here. Clean off the mud with a putty knife, keep checking every 6 months. Don’t bother doing anything else.

Comment: Yeah, I think if the wood is mostly solid, that sistering the joists would only rob you of the ability to perform the periodic inspections.  Might be worth taking a sharpie and tracing a border around each spot so you can tell if the damage is encroaching—I doubt you'll remember what each spot looks like from the previous inspection.